# Java code for converting C program to Control Flow Graph

Tags: java, c, static-analysis, control-flow

I require a java code for converting a C program into a control flow graph.

Can any one please help me out with it?

Comment: Do you have to use Java, or just something that runs on a JVM?

Comment: What help do you have in mind? Create a parser, then semantic analyzer, then build a flow graph.

Comment: Why do you "have" to use Java?

Comment: I "have" to use Java because that is the what has been specified by the university for any project.

Comment: @Sowmya Prayaga: Is this a project for a specific course or a degree requirement (such as a Master's project)?

Comment: It is my master's project with july 12th as the deadline.

Comment: @Sowmya Prayaga: Just out of curiosity, what approach did you end up using? How did it work out?

Answer (score 2):

July 12<sup>th</sup> is going to be a tough deadline to meet, but you can do it.

Here is the general strategy that I would use if I were completing this project myself:

1. Preprocess the input C file (also called the *translation unit*). This generates the *preprocessed translation unit*.
2. Parse the preprocessed translation unit as an abstract syntax tree (AST).
3. Traverse the AST, creating a graph node `n` for each function declaration. Add (*function name*, `n`) to a map.
4. Traverse the AST, building a graph of the control flow. Consider how you are going to represent the following, special cases in the control flow graph:

   - Labelled statements
   - `if`/`else`
   - `if` not followed by `else`.
   - `goto`
   - `switch`
   - Fall-through cases and `break` within `switch`.
   - Loops such as `do`...`while`, `while`, and `for`.
   - `break` within a loop
   - `continue` within a loop
   - `return`
   - Regular function calls
   - Calling the target of a function pointer
   - End of a `void` function definition (no `return`)
   - End of `int main()` and `int main(int, char**)`, which does not require `return`
   - `exit`
   - Intermediate values
5. Output the graph in [DOT format](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html).

You may want to use this test program, which I think has all of the "special" cases:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void usage(const char *arg0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [INTEGER]\n", arg0);
    fprintf(stderr, "Dummy program\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int g_a;

void init()
{
    g_a = 3;
}

int return_4()
{
    return 4;
}

void uninit()
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc <= 1) {
        usage(argv[0]);
    }

    if (argc > 2) {
        printf("You only need to pass one argument.\n");
    }
    else {
        init();
    }

    const int i = atoi(argv[1]);
    int j;
before_switch: j = 0;
switch_i: switch (i) {
        case 3:
            for(; j < 3; ++j)
                printf(".");
        case 17:
            for(; j < 17; ++j)
                printf(".");
            if (i == 3 || i == 17)
                printf("\n");
        case -4:
            printf("You picked one of my favorite numbers (17, 3, and -4)!\n");
            break;

        case -1:
            printf("Cleaning up\n");
            goto cleanup;

        default:
            printf("I don't like that number.\n");
    }

    j = 0;
do_loop_1: do {
        if (j++ % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        if (j == 10)
            break;

        printf("j is %d.\n", j);
    } while(j < 30);

    j = 10;
    while (j > 0) {
        if (4 == return_4())
            break;
        --j;
    }

    void (*voidFn)() = &uninit;
    voidFn();
    init();

cleanup:
    uninit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would also use the following open source libraries:

1. [JCPP](http://www.anarres.org/projects/jcpp/), a pure Java implementation of the C preprocessor, for preprocessing the translation unit
2. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) for parsing along with the [ANTLR C grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1153358328744/C.g)
3. [Grappa](http://www2.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/) for the graph data structures and graph drawing (if required)

Comment: Your example doesn't cover the nasty things you can write in C.  It is perfectly legal to put a label in the middle of a block, and **goto** it from outside the block.  It is perfectly legal to put a build switch statments whose cases are not well structured.  In Gcc, you have goto indirect.   Most versions of C allow setjmp.  All of these can make what appear to be structured program into a spaghetti tangle.

Comment: @Ira: True. I had forgotten about these features of C. Hopefully, though, following this strategy will yield a program that *could* handle these additional cases.